# How to install dategrep on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I want to grep lines with date and time stamp. I came across this command called

```
dategrep
```

on internet.
I am trying to install this on my 64 bit Ubuntu system. I downloaded a Debian package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/dateutils/download. I used

```
sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb
```

to install it. But it don't seem to be present on my system when I use

```
which dategrep
```

command to find it. Can anyone tell me how to get through this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `dpkg -L dateutils` to find out what has been installed.

In specific, you should look for binaries in `/bin, /sbin` etc.

Comment: Yes.  AND If the ubuntu package mentioned by the OP is the same as the debian package on my system, then `dategrep` is installed as `/usr/bin/dateutils.dgrep`.  All of the executables (and their man pages) in that package are `dateutils.?????`- I would guess that when `dateutils` was packaged, there was at least one conflict with binaries in some other package, so the decision was made to rename the `dateutils` binaries by prefixing them with `dateutils.`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple search reveals that the package is maintained on [github](https://github.com/mdom/dategrep), but the installation procedure suggested there is incomplete and contains assumptions. Use the following commands:

```
release=0.54
wget https://github.com/mdom/dategrep/releases/download/$release/dategrep-standalone-big
sudo cp dategrep-standalone-big /usr/local/bin/dategrep
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/dategrep
```

`0.54` is current version as of today, for future versions you need to change the first line.

Comment: I tried this one. I get http 404 error. Do i need to make any changes in that code. And this github is totally new for me. Can you guide me please.

Comment: When I ran `wget`, a  file called dategrep-standalone-big was generated. When I changed its extension to `.pl`, and run the `cp` command, I get error like this `cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/swatesh/bin/dategrep’: No such file or directory`. What's going wrong here.  Even if I don't add `.pl` extension I get same error.

Comment: I got it. I logged in as root and used the same commands before edits. Like this `root@ubuntu:/home/swatesh# cp dategrep-standalone-big /bin/dategrep` and `chmod +x /bin/dategrep`.

Comment: Yes, the effect will be the same. Good for you!

Comment: Regarding GitHub, it's a huge repository of open source projects. It is quite powerful for collaboration, but as a casual user you just need to know that each project has (should have) readme page with further instructions. There are also wikis and issue tracking parts which you may use to get information from. If information about a project is scarce it means it is badly maintained.

Comment: @SwateshPakhare Don't put manually-installed software in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, that will confuse the package manager. Put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @Gilles How would a perl script manually put in `/usr/bin` confuse any package manager?

Comment: @techraf Ok, “confuse” may be the wrong word for `dpkg` with a file in `/usr/bin`. The point is that the package manager won't know about it. For a file in `/usr/bin`, in practice, that means that it may get overwritten. For files elsewhere, that could prevent a directory from being created or removed, for example. And it will confuse the system administrator (i.e. you in a year's time).